# Creation of context fail when JUNIT test is launched

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I created a small junit test that is launched from my application client.
My server is glassfish 3.1.1 .
When i run the test i get this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

I have already added the propreties to the context but nothing changed.
This how i set up my context:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws NamingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        System.out.println("launch");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming");

        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


        // optional.  Defaults to localhost.  Only needed if web server is running
        // on a different host than the appserver   
        //props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

        // optional.  Defaults to 3700.  Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
        //props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
        Context annuaire = new InitialContext(props);
        GeoBeanRemote service = (GeoBeanRemote) annuaire.lookup(GeoBeanRemote.class.getName());
        BeanProvider.setGeoBean(service);
    }
```

app-serv.rt and gf-client are added to my run-test.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using GlassFish v3+ you should only need gf-client.jar in your classpath

Comment: Can u show the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue when jndi.properties was missing from my classpath.

**Addendum:**
I'm feeling a bit silly here, but I don't think you can set your initial context that way. I note though that JNDI properties don't even need to be set on Glassfish, so color me confused.

Comment: What's the difference between putting the properties via the code or writing them in a jndi.properties file and loading them ? Can you paste your jndi.properties please ?